# Как отсортировать файлы по дате в php?

Tags: php

```
        $catalog = opendir($dir);

        while ($filename = readdir($catalog )) // перебираем наш каталог 
        {  
        $filename = $dir."/".$filename;  
        include_once($filename); // один раз подрубаем, чтоб не повторяться 
        }

        closedir($catalog);
```

С помощью этого кода подключаю файлы но мне нужно чтобы они подключались от нового к старому, то есть отсортировать перед подключением. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать массив с файлами и дополнить его информацией о дате изменения файла https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filemtime.php
После отсортировать по значению. Так как время изменения в Unix просто сравниваете значения
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php