# Как сортировать файлы по дате в PHP?

Tags: php, файлы, сортировка

Никак не могу найти способ, чтобы сделать вывод содержимого каталога с сортировкой по дате. От нового файла или папке к самой старой. Содержимое каталога выводиться, но как попало. Нужно, чтобы сортировка работала с вот этим скриптом.

```html
<?php
$dir =   'repository/'.$_SESSION['logged_user']->homedir;
if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    echo "Папка <b>{$dir}</b> не существует!";
    exit();
}
$aFiles = scandir($dir);
?>

<div class="table-stats order-table ov-h">
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Имя</th>
            <th>Дата</th>
            <th>Скачать</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php $num=1; foreach ($aFiles as $item): if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $num; ?></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-check fa-color" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo iconv('windows-1251','UTF-8', pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_BASENAME)); ?></td>
        <td><? $filename = $dir.'/'.$item; echo date ("d/m/Y H:i:s", filemtime($filename)); ?></td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-download fa-color" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <? echo  '<a class="btn-down" href="repository/">Скачать</a>'; ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
<?php $num++; endforeach; ?>
    </tbody></table>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004216/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2-php?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как отсортировать файлы по дате в php?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004216/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2-php)